# std::map design : use a std::string for the map key and the stored object name (member)

Tags: c++, key, stdstring, stdmap

I tried to find the best way to design a named objects storage : *std::map< std::string, NamedObject >*

I would like to use a *std::map* where key is the name of the object. And in the other hand, I would like my object to be identifiable by itself, like using a *getName()* method and returning that name. The thing which irritates me is I didn't found a better way other than set two copies of the *std::string*, one for the key and one inside the object as member.

If anyone have a suggestion ?

EDIT:

Basically, this is a resources manager. The most important thing is to find a resource by his name. But sometime, when I have the resource alone under the hand, I would like to be able to know his name. In the first place, I thought about a vector... But the idea to loop trought it and ask every object his name to find the right one was bad  to me.

Comment: sorry, i meant to say: boost multi_index_container will allow this, but it's extra complication you may not want.

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for a solution easy to use as the std::map. I'm thinkin about removing the name from the object and use the iterator to identify it, but I don't like to use a part of the std::map in other places than the map management.

Comment: yes, it's a limitation of all the associative containers in the standard library. Having said that, most problems can be expressed in terms of "naming" and "doing" as separate concepts, so it's normally appropriate to separate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you have such tough requirements for the memory? 
If yes, I think you can create any "Hash" function for the object name like this:

```
int hash( const std::string& obj_name );
```

and then use

```
std::multimap<int, NamedObject>
```

but it seems like extra complexity

Comment: in this way you will not save copy of object's name but every time you must call hash function